# Trying to split up a string separated with ; VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, console, console-application

I'm writing a musical transposition application (in simple VB Console) and I want the program to split up a string of different notes separated with ;'s, looking like this:

```
'C blues scale
Dim strNotesString As String = "C; Eb; F; F#; G; Bb"
```

Can anyone recommend a way I can achieve this? I would put each separate note into an array.

```
Dim strTmpNotes() As String
strTmpNotes(0) = "C"
strTmpNotes(1) = "Eb"
'And so on
```

Thanks in advance

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.Split:

```
Dim strNotesString As String = "C; Eb; F; F#; G; Bb"
Dim strTmpNotes() As String = strNotesString.Split("; ")
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim strTmpNotes() As String = strNotesString.Replace(" ", "").Split(";"c)
```

You could also use regular expressions:

```
Dim strTmpNotes() As String = New Regex(";\s*").Split(strNotesString)
```

I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

```
Dim strNotesString As String = "C; Eb; F; F#; G; Bb"
Dim notes() As String = strNotesString.Split("; ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, as .NET has this capability built in.

```
strTmpNotes = strNotesString.Split(';')
```

Then run a Trim on each of the individual strings in the resulting array using a for loop.